# How to define af function that pick nested property without loosing type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

i am looking for a way to select a nested property in a object of objects without loosing the type information of the given property using Typescript.

This could be the input for the function:

```
var fields = {email: {$: 'test'}, password: {$: 1}};
```

I would like to have a function that transforms this fields object into

```
var result = {email: 'test', password: 1}
```

Without loosing the type information on each fields. The email stays a string and password stays a number.

The real use case is to pick the value field out of some form data object in order serilize it into JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Typescript 2.8 (unreleased at the time of writing, will be released in March 2018). This involves using conditional types and their associated  inference behavior:

```
type Unpacked<T> =
    T extends { $: infer U } ? U : // if T has $ then we extarct the type of $
    T;

var fields = {email: {$: 'test'}, password: {$: 1}};

function unpack<T>(obj: T) : { [P in keyof T] : Unpacked<T[P]>} {
    return  <any>null; // dummy implementation
}

var r = unpack(fields) // Will be typed as { email: string, password: number }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I might have to wait for Typescript 2.8 to be released then :-) Which parts of this implementation is based on Typescript 2.8 :-) ? Only the conditional part?

Comment: @user2553885 `Unpacked<T>` is what depends on 2.8, which is kind of the heart of the solution, but you will not have to wait long :)

Comment: Ah okay :-) I was just wondering if the infer keyword also was a part of the 2.8 update. Thanks for the help, that solves a lot of my issues with typescript :-) !